# How to convert Timestamp into Date format in java

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a time stamp like this(form a json response) :

"/Date(1479974400000-0800)/"

I'm trying this function to convert time stamp into date:

```
public String getDate() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();
    return date;
}
```

**How to convert this Timestamp into Date format?**

Comment: why is not working? what is the exception?

Comment: Is `time` your string? If so, it's not clear how you'd expect that to work... but "It not works" is *never* enough information to include in a question. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: You cannot do `DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal)`. It would require that `DateFormat` had a static method `format` that accepted two arguments. The `format` method is not static, so you need to create a `DateFormat` object and call the method on that object. The method exists in overloaded versions taking 1 and 3 arguments, respectively, not 2.

Comment: I will remember ur suggestions Sir @ Jon Skeet,@ Joe C

Comment: I'm trying that @OleV.V.

Comment: There is no exception seen till now. I'm still trying to extract required string from my json response.@ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution works
for me is like this:

```
 String str = obj.getString("eventdate").replaceAll("\\D+", "");
String upToNCharacters = str.substring(0, Math.min(str.length(), 13));
DateFormat timeZoneFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
timeZoneFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8"));

Date time = new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(upToNCharacters));
//                                System.out.println(time);
model.setDate(String.valueOf(timeZoneFormat.format(time)));
```

Use ***time*** variable where you want

Answer (score 4):

### Parse directly into an OffsetDateTime

Java can directly parse your string into an `OffsetDateTime`. Use this formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter JSON_TIMESTAMP_FORMATTER 
        = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendLiteral("/Date(")
                .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS, 1, 19, SignStyle.NEVER)
                .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
                .appendOffset("+HHMM", "Z")
                .appendLiteral(")/")
                .toFormatter();
```

Then just do:

```
    String time = "/Date(1479974400000-0800)/";
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(time, JSON_TIMESTAMP_FORMATTER);
    System.out.println(odt);
```

Output is:

> 2016-11-24T00:00-08:00

In your string `1479974400000` is a count of milliseconds since the epoch of Jan 1, 1970 at 00:00 UTC, and `-0800` is an offset of -8 hours 0 minutes from UTC (corresponding for example to Pacific Standard Time). To parse the milliseconds we need to parse the seconds since the epoch (all digits except the last three) and then the millisecond of second (the last three digits). By specifying the width of the milliseconds field as 3 Java does this. For it to work it requires that the number is at least 4 digits and not negative, that is not within the first 999 milliseconds after the epoch or earlier. This is also why I specify in the formatter that the seconds must not be signed.

I specified `Z` for offset zero, I don’t know if you may ever receive this. An offset of `+0000` for zero can still be parsed too.

### Original answer: parse the milliseconds and the offset separately and combine

First I want to make sure the timestamp I have really lives up to the format I expect. I want to make sure if one day it doesn’t, I don’t just pretend and the user will get incorrect results without knowing they are incorrect. So for parsing the timestamp string, since I didn’t find a date-time format that would accept milliseconds since the epoch, I used a regular expression:

```
    String time = "/Date(1479974400000-0800)/";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("/Date\\((\\d+)([+-]\\d{4})\\)/");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(time);
    if (m.matches()) {
        Instant i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(m.group(1)));
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

This prints:

```
2016-11-24T08:00:00Z
```

If you want an old-fashioned `java.util.Date`:

```
        System.out.println(Date.from(i));
```

On my computer it prints

```
Thu Nov 24 09:00:00 CET 2016
```

This will depend on your time zone.

It is not clear to me whether you need to use the zone offset and for what purpose. You may retrieve it from the matcher like this:

```
        ZoneOffset zo = ZoneOffset.of(m.group(2));
        System.out.println(zo);
```

This prints:

```
-08:00
```

The zone offset can be used with other time classes, like for instance `OffsetDateTime`. For example:

```
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(i, zo);
        System.out.println(odt);
```

I hesitate to mention this, though, because I cannot know whether it is what you need. In any case, it prints:

```
2016-11-24T00:00-08:00
```

Comment: Great! This (improving a two-year-old answer) is inspiring!

Answer (score 1):

If by date you mean Date instance, then you can do this:

```
new Date(Long.parseLong("\/Date(1479974400000-0800)\/".substring(7, 20)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this info in holding the String representing an Epoch and a TimeZone

**"/Date(1479974400000-0800)/"**

you need to get rid off the all the not necessary parts and keeping only the 
**1479974400000-0800**

then the epoch is **1479974400000** and I guess the Timezone is **0800**

then do:

```
String[] allTimeInfo = "1310928623-0800".split("-");
DateFormat timeZoneFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
timeZoneFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-8"));
Date time = new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(allTimeInfo[0]));
System.out.println(time);
System.out.println(timeZoneFormat.format(time));
```

Comment: My guess is the dash between the digits is a sign and part of the time zone. If so, the zone offset is not **0800** as your guess said, but **-0800**.