# convert epoch json format string to date on java

Tags: java

I have a string I recieve from service is a date, this date have this format `"/Date(1607490140063-0600)/"` is a string, now I need convert from a string to a date format on java, I try differents ways but no work

```
String endTime = getPunchTime();
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date d2 = timeFormat.parse(endTime);
```

Comment: Is it time in milliseconds before the dash? And what is this after the dash?

Comment: the received date is : /Date(1607490140063-0600)/ or 1607490140063-0600

Comment: @MustafaPoya  is "/Date(1607490140063-0600)/"

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I just updated [my answer to the linked original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40946731/5772882) with a new solution that I consider more elegant. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a helper method for parsing the value, and use regex to parse the text, e.g. like this:

```java
static OffsetDateTime parseJsonDate(String s) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/Date\\((-?\\d+)([+-]\\d{4})\\)/");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (! m.matches())
        throw new DateTimeParseException("Not a valid JSON Date string: " + s, s, 0);
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(m.group(1))).atOffset(ZoneOffset.of(m.group(2)));
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(parseJsonDate("/Date(1607490140063-0600)/"));
```

*Output*

```
2020-12-08T23:02:20.063-06:00
```