# How to parse properly Date string to java.util.Date when deserializing JSON to Java POJO with Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, date, parsing, deserialization

I am implementing an application that gets the data from certin endponts in json formats and tries to deserialize tem to Java Objects but I have problems with the parsing of the date in the JSON.This is how the Date looks like in the JSON: "/Date(1633122000000+0300)/" and I cannot find information in Google how to successfully parse this format.

```
{
  "Date": "/Date(1633122000000+0300)/",
  "Filled": 0,
  "Needed": 0,
  "Paid": 0
}
```

This is the pojo I use to deserialize the data to using Jackson ObjectMapper:

```
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TimeByDateSheet {

    @JsonProperty("Date")
    @JsonFormat(timezone = "GMT+03:00")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class, as=Date.class)
    private Date date;
    
    @JsonProperty("Filled")
    private Long filled;
 
    @JsonProperty("Needed")
    private Long needed;
    
   @JsonProperty("Paid")
   private Integer paid;

}
```

And here is my DateDeserializer:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

@Override
public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) 
throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
         new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.getDefault());
    String dateStr = jsonParser.getText();
    Date date;
    try{
        date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateStr);
    }catch(ParseException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return date;
}
```

}

But it does not work correctly. I get the following exception:

> Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52760', transport: 'socket'
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "/Date(1633035600000+0300)/" (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.dataart.forecasts.pojo.timebydate.TimeByDateSheet["Date"])
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:392)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:351)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1821)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:315)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:355)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4675)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3630)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3613)
> at com.dataart.forecasts.DataProcessor.deserializeTimeByDateSheetsList(DataProcessor.java:198)
> at com.dataart.forecasts.ForecastReportApplication.main(ForecastReportApplication.java:50)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "/Date(1633035600000+0300)/"
> at com.dataart.forecasts.DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializer.java:28)
> at com.dataart.forecasts.DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializer.java:16)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:313)
> ... 10 more
> Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "/Date(1633035600000+0300)/"
> at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
> at com.dataart.forecasts.DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializer.java:26)
> ... 13 more

Could someone help me, please. I searched a lot in internet but could not find a solution.
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Related: [How to convert Timestamp into Date format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945793/how-to-convert-timestamp-into-date-format-in-java)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a problem generating the JSON. I really don't think you want to have the dates formatted like that. Right now, you have some odd text surrounding a unix timestamp in milliseconds followed by a zone offset. You are also using the old and rather frowned-upon Date and SimpleDateFormat classes rather than the newer `java.time` API. However, it is possible to deserialize your date format. Here is one way:

```
public class DateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) 
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/Date\\((\\d+)([+-]\\d+)\\)/");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jsonParser.getText());
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String timestamp = matcher.group(1);
            String offset = matcher.group(2);
            Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(timestamp));
            ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of(offset));
            instant = zdt.toInstant();
            return Date.from(instant);
        } else {
          throw new RuntimeException("Invalid format: " + jsonParser.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The odd format is regularly seen with JSON (both with and without the offset). I don’t know where it comes from.

Comment: @OleV.V. Hmm. At my company we use JSON and our dates always come out like "2021-11-08T21:36:15.234Z".

Comment: Lucky you. :-) [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is preferable not just because it’s more readable but also because it’s a more widely accepted standard and also therefore easier to handle in Java and elsewhere. I think the same is the case with us. I haven’t gone through the 20+ REST services with which we exchange JSON, but those I’ve seen do ise ISO 8601.

Comment: @OleV.V. I think the key is that we use our own subclass of `ObjectMapper` and in the constructor we set `super.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);` and `super.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());`

Comment: That latter class is known as fully qualified `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule`

Comment: @DavidConrad Your solution worked very well, just refactored the pattern a bit in order to match some slightly different dates in other jsons.

Comment: @DavidConrad Sounds like what I am doing too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

For this answer I am assuming:

1. The time in your JSON may come with or without the UTC offset.
2. You can go all-in on java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and declare your variable to be of type `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`, for example (not `Date`).

**For JSON that comes with an offset** such as `+0300` declare your variable an `OffsetDateTime`. Then use the following deserializer.

```
public class OdtDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter JSON_DATE_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendLiteral("/Date(")
            .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
            .appendOffset("+HHMM", "Z")
            .appendLiteral(")/")
            .toFormatter();

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException {
        String dateStr = jsonParser.getText();
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(dateStr, JSON_DATE_FORMATTER);
    }

}
```

**For JSON that comes without offset** like `/Date(1636510000000)/` declare your variable `Instant`. Use a similar deserializer. Leave out the offset from the formatter. Parse into an `Instant` — the syntax is a bit different.

```
public class InstantDeserializerWIthoutOffset extends JsonDeserializer<Instant> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter JSON_DATE_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendLiteral("/Date(")
            .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
            .appendLiteral(")/")
            .toFormatter();

    @Override
    public Instant deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException {
        String dateStr = jsonParser.getText();
        return JSON_DATE_FORMATTER.parse(dateStr, Instant::from);
    }

}
```

**For JSON that may come with or without the offset** still use `Instant` and just modify the formatter of the latter deserializer to include an optional offset:

```
    private static final DateTimeFormatter JSON_DATE_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendLiteral("/Date(")
            .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendOffset("+HHMM", "Z")
            .optionalEnd()
            .appendLiteral(")/")
            .toFormatter();
```

**If you cannot modify your POJO class** and need to stay with `Date`, modify my `Instant` deserializer into a `Date` deserializer by changing the declaration and returning a `Date` like this:

```
        String dateStr = jsonParser.getText();
        Instant inst = JSON_DATE_FORMATTER.parse(dateStr, Instant::from);
        return Date.from(inst);
```

Answer (score 1):

Final solution catching both: /Date(1633035600000+0300)/ and /Date(-62135596800000)/ (the latter was also present at one place in oneof the JSONs). Thank you @DavidConrad

```
@Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String dateString = jsonParser.getText();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/Date\\((-)?(\\d+)([+-]\\d+)?\\)/");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dateString);
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid format: " + dateString);
        }
        String timestamp = matcher.group(2);
        String offset = matcher.group(3);
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(timestamp));
        if (nonNull(offset)) {
            ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of(offset));
            instant = zdt.toInstant();
        }
        return Date.from(instant);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@DavidConrad Thank you, I will try your solution.
By the way, for now I made a workaround that works for me for now:

```
@Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormattter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String dateStr = jsonParser.getText();
        String timeZone = dateStr.substring(dateStr.indexOf("+") + 1, dateStr.indexOf(")"));
        String timeZoneShift = String.format("%s:%s",
                timeZone.substring(0, timeZone.length()/2),
                timeZone.substring(timeZone.length()/2));
        dateFormattter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(String.format("GMT+%s", timeZoneShift)));
        Long millis = 0L;
        if (dateStr.contains("+") && !dateStr.contains("-")) {
            millis = Long.parseLong(dateStr.substring(dateStr.indexOf("(") + 1, dateStr.indexOf("+")));
        } else if (dateStr.contains("+") && !dateStr.contains("-")) {
            millis = Long.parseLong(dateStr.substring(dateStr.indexOf("(") + 1, dateStr.indexOf(")")));
        }
        Date date = new Date(millis);
        String stringDate= dateFormattter.format(date);
        try {
            date = dateFormattter.parse(stringDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your temporary solution. It’s overly complicated. Also the delimiting of the offset (for example `+0300`) doesn’t seem to take into account that it may begin with a minus rather than a plus. And after what David Conrad wisely said, we’d be more interested in seeing your solution using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: *just refactored the pattern a bit in order to match some slightly different dates in other jsons* How are those other JSONs different? It’s hard to tell from your code — are they coming without the UTC offset? As I mentioned I have seen that before.

Comment: here is one particular date that was in that format: /Date(-62135596800000)/
so i had to modify the regex to catch it too: /Date\((-)?(\d+)([+-]?\d+)?\)

Comment: Ah, year 1. `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z`. Silly to represent a dummy value that way, but I guess you will have to live with it? I haven’t tested the code in my answer with negative milliseconds since the epoch, results may be inaccurate.